# How to add a variable to the URL on click?

Tags: javascript, php

I have a delte link `[Delete]` which onClick should attach a couple of variables to the URL.

```
<a id="close-frame-course" href="action=#?delete_course&course_id=<?php echo $courseid[$count]; ?>"><div class="close-frame">X</div></a>
```

The current URL is like `example.com/dashboard.php?page=all`

I was to add `action=delete_course&course_id=1` upon clicking on the link. But this seems not right. I can't get the values in js. Could you help me to fix it?

Comment: if you do not want the page to make a full page refresh, you might need to consider using an XMLHttpRequest

Comment: @Ghost: How's that possible?

Comment: just search online about that, don't worry you won't have shortage of content regarding XMLHttpRequest. or if you have used jquery, just use ajax

Comment: Can't we do this through simple methods? or JS?

Comment: well if you want a simple method, just redirect it to that PHP page that processes the deletion. just remove that `#` on your url page pass the appropriate id that the PHP will use in `$_GET`

Comment: Can I have an explanation for the downvote?

Comment: sorry but no i did not. but my opinion is its still too broad. thats just my opinion.

Answer (score -1):

Add class in your html code as you are already using id.
I have used abc for example.

class="abc"

Now in your jQuery code get the href value and use window.location for redirection.

```
$(".abc").click(function(){
    var txt = $(this).attr('href');
    var url="example.com/dashboard.php?page=all"
    window.location = url+txt;
});
```

Hope this will help you..

Comment: I'm curious where you got information about jQuery being used anywhere?